# NodeJs check the salt of a sha-256 encrypted string

Tags: node.js, sails.js, salt, bcrypt, sha256

My client is sending me a SHA-256 encrypted string. And also it is having a  salt. Myself and my client both are knowing the above salt. I need to check weather the string is having correct salt or not.

Comment: Is this salt prepended, appended or is inside of the original string?

Comment: SHA256 is a hashing function, not an encryption algorithm. If you have the string and the salt, just hash them and compare to the hashed string?

Comment: @ezrepotein It is appended ( hashed using SHA-256 with a predefined salt agreed to between both parties )

Comment: @MattHarrison I don't have string. Only the things I have, are the salt and the hashed string. I need to check weather the salt is exists in the hashed string or not.

Comment: You can only check if salt is correct if you have the original string.

Comment: @ezrepotein is there a way to grab the salt from the hashed and salted string, because I don't know the Original string. I am only knowing the salt they have used to salted and the salted string.

Comment: @ErangaKapukotuwa no.

Comment: The purpose of hashing algorithms is that they work only one way around. You can always hash the string but you cannot "unhash" it back to original. One can only check correction of given original string (ie. by client) with your hashed copy (ie. stored in database) by hashing and salting the original and comparing them.

Comment: @ezrepotein and MattHarrison. Thank you for answering.